# Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection from Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, android-security, android-securityexception

App was developed in React Native
Play Stopre Issue-
found that your app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users. Apps with these vulnerabilities can expose user information or damage a user’s device, and may be considered to be in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy.

I don't use any Unity framework. Please tell me how to solve the problem

Comment: I have the same issue. I am not using any Unity framework and even I don't know what causes the security vulnerability.

Comment: hay, did you found any solutions to this?